# How to list all files that end in ".doc" that exist in a directory and subdirectories whose name contain a certain word WITHOUT piping?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, find

For example, If I have a directory called `Test` and it has a file named `test.doc` and `String` and a subdirectory `Tests` with `doc2.doc`
So the output in this case would just be `test.doc` because the subdirectory does not contain the word `test`.

Comment: If ./Test/test.doc is listed, then why ./Tests/doc2.doc is not?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani because doc2.doc does not contain the string "test" if it was doc2test.doc then it would or if the subdirectory Tests had another file that contains the string "test"

Comment: You'd better give some examples that are easy to follow, because I can't make heads nor tails of your description.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
find -type f -ipath '*test*/*.doc'
```

Answer (score 0):

This `find` command will search all files in the Test directory and all sub-directories and list any files which contain the string "test".

```
find Test -type f -exec grep -l test {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
cd /path/Test || exit

find . -type f -name "*test*.doc" -exec grep -l "String" {} \;
```

Find files with "test" in their names that have the word "String" in their contents.